# Tracking Down a Problem User

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance

How do I track down a user that may be running a relatively quick query, but running it excessively?  For examples, they may:

- be running a report over and over and over again
- have a book set on their keyboard
- have a refresh interval set very low

Other users may be running the exact same queries and reports, but their load on the system is minuscule.

I know how to track down problem queries, waits, etc., but I'm looking for a cumulative user-specific problem.

Comment: Is said user/group running a known set of queries, an unknown set of queries, or a mix of both?

Comment: Unknown.  We found a user just by accident when we were tracing a certain report and the same user showed up running it every minute.  To them, the report was running fine each time, but the cumulative amount of data it was pulling over the network to their remote site was significant.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from sp_whoisactive as mentioned in earlier answer, i can suggest running extended events for the type of query you want to track.

You can use the events and action as mentioned in the log [Tracing Query Performance with Extended Events](https://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/tracing-query-performance-extended-events/)

I really like the extended events for the amount of data you can capture out and its not that expensive depending upon how much you capture.

Additionally you can use `sp_blitzwho` [Forget sp_Who and sp_Who2:
sp_BlitzWho tells you what’s really happening.](https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/sp_blitzwho/)

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations.  I reviewed sp_BlitzWho, sp_BlitzCache, and sp_whoisactive.  They are great for tracking down individual problems.  My problem is cumulative.  I am looking at well-written queries that are run by an large agency 1000's of times daily.  The problem is when 30% of those calls are by 1 user.  Perhaps their refresh rate is seconds instead of minutes.  The data sent back may be a small report, but it is across a slow network to a remote site.  I want the user running a disproportional share of calls or using a higher amount of resources then all else over time.

Answer (score 0):

Few options I can think of.... scheduling Adam Machanics sp_whoisactivesp and logging the output, sp available here: http://whoisactive.com/

Example code that you could schedule in a job to run at some frequent interval

```
--run the sp first to get the schema returned to create a table to dump the results 
--into
declare @sql varchar(1000)

exec sp_whoisactive @return_schema = 1,
                @schema = @sql output

--this has your create table statement
select @sql

--once the the table is created, schedule the below in a job which will dump the 
--output into your temp table created above
exec sp_whoisactive @destination_table = '<table name created in above step>'
```

A better option in the case that the query doesn't run very long... is sp_blitzCache, available here: https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/
This sp analyzes your plan cache and returns the most intensive queries in terms of work involved. You can further filter the results for your needs... For example @SortOrder parameter allows you to sort results by Reads, Writes, Executions... execute with the help option to learn more on each parameter

```
sp_blitzCache @help = 1
```

Maybe running on @SortOrder = 'Executions' will help you find queries being executed very frequently. There are probably some more methods out there but I would start with these two and gather some data from them.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations.  I reviewed sp_BlitzWho, sp_BlitzCache, and sp_whoisactive.  They are great for tracking down individual problems.  My problem is cumulative.  I am looking at well-written queries that are run by an large agency 1000's of times daily.  The problem is when 30% of those calls are by 1 user.  Perhaps their refresh rate is seconds instead of minutes.  The data sent back may be a small report, but it is across a slow network to a remote site.  I want the user running a disproportional share of calls or using a higher amount of resources then all else over time.